# UnicodeDecodeError: 'gbk' codec can't decode byte 0xa5 in position 6: illegal multibyte sequence

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

> Using python2.x code in Python3.8 get an error run follow code
> import pandas as pd
> from Crypto.Cipher import AES
> from Crypto.Hash import MD5
> import time
>
> ```
> def build_codeword(ID, trapdoor):
>     ID_index = MD5.new()
>     ID_index.update(str.encode(ID))
>     ECB_cipher = AES.new(trapdoor, AES.MODE_ECB)
>     return ECB_cipher.encrypt(ID_index.digest()).encode("hex")
>
> def search_index(document, trapdoor):
>     search_result = []
>     data_index = pd.read_csv(document)
>     data_index = data_index.values
>     # start_time = time.time()
>     for row in range(data_index.shape[0]):
>         if build_codeword(row, trapdoor) in data_index[row]:
>             search_result.append(row)
>
>     # print time.time() - start_time
>     return search_result
>
> if __name__ == "__main__":
>
>     index_file_name = input("Please input the index file you want to search:  ")
>     keyword_trapdoor = input("Please input the file stored the trapdoor you want to search:  ")
>     keyword_trapdoor = open(keyword_trapdoor).read().strip()
>     search_result = search_index(index_file_name, keyword_trapdoor)
>     print("The identifiers of files that contain the keyword are: \n", search_result)
> import pandas as pd
> from Crypto.Cipher import AES
> from Crypto.Hash import MD5
> import time
>
> def build_codeword(ID, trapdoor):
>     ID_index = MD5.new()
>     ID_index.update(str.encode(ID))
>     ECB_cipher = AES.new(trapdoor, AES.MODE_ECB)
>     return ECB_cipher.encrypt(ID_index.digest()).encode("hex")
>
> def search_index(document, trapdoor):
>     search_result = []
>     data_index = pd.read_csv(document)
>     data_index = data_index.values
>     # start_time = time.time()
>     for row in range(data_index.shape[0]):
>         if build_codeword(row, trapdoor) in data_index[row]:
>             search_result.append(row)
>
>     # print time.time() - start_time
>     return search_result
>
> if __name__ == "__main__":
>
>     index_file_name = input("Please input the index file you want to search:  ")
>     keyword_trapdoor = input("Please input the file stored the trapdoor you want to search:  ")
>     keyword_trapdoor = open(keyword_trapdoor).read().strip()
>     search_result = search_index(index_file_name, keyword_trapdoor)
>     print("The identifiers of files that contain the keyword are: \n", search_result)
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "E:/Searchable_Encryption-master/Searchable_Encryption-master/sse_search.py",
> ```
>
> line 28, in 
> keyword_trapdoor = open(keyword_trapdoor).read().strip()
> UnicodeDecodeError: 'gbk' codec can't decode byte 0xa5 in position 6: illegal multibyte sequence

Comment: I have no time to debug. You should reduce your file at minimum (with the error): it is easier to you to understand the error, and for us to help you. But: you use `open` without specifying an encoding, so the system will take one for you, and as you see, the guess is wrong. So, do you know the encoding of the trapdoor? Give to `open` such the encoding, and so you solve the problem

Comment: @Giacomo Catenazzi i did for trapdoor encoding but it is little different actually dont know how to open with encoding  here keyword_trapdoor = open(keyword_trapdoor).read().strip()

Comment: @Giacomo Catenazz keyword_type_list = open(encoding=keyword_list_file_name).read().split(",") but i got an error

Comment: `keyword_trapdoor = open(keyword_trapdoor, encoding='utf-8').read().strip()`

Comment: @Giacomo Catenazz getting this another error UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode bytes in position 3-4: invalid continuation byte

Comment: `utf-8` is just an example. You should substitute the name of the encoding of your file. We cannot guess it. You must know it (or do a guess, e.g. with a standard editor, and check with different encoding, until you see correct text)

Comment: @Giacomo Catenazz you mean to check with txt file or csv file in mkeyword_trapdoor = open(keyword_trapdoor, encoding='input(Files_name_asCVS)').read().strip()y project like

Comment: @Giacomo Catenazz  check with txt file or csv file in my project keyword_trapdoor = open(keyword_trapdoor,encoding='input(Files_name_asCVS)').read().strip()y project like where i try and test different csv file in same directory of my project  that return an error unknown encoding is there is any other way to check for utf-8 encoding like as a default

Comment: actually select a keywords form from my keywords list from csv file which consist of both integers and string are mixed in CSV which test and pass of my code i got an  error TypeError: descriptor 'encode' for 'str' objects doesn't apply to a 'int' object

Comment: @Giacomo Catenazz actually i select a keywords list from my keywords list from csv file name  Advanced_Meter.csv which consist of both integers and string are mixed in CSV file that i have test my codes for these parameters like on my python build_index.py 

Please input the file to be encrypted:  Advanced_Meter.csv

Please input the file stored the master key:  masterkey

please input the file stores keyword type:  keywordlist

Finished but  i got an  error TypeError: descriptor 'encode' for 'str' objects doesn't apply to a 'int' object

Comment: You should open the file `keyword_trapdoor` with one good text editor which support multiple encoding. Then check which encoding has your file (when you can read all characters, you may be on the right way). Then check python documentation about encoding, and check which it is the name of such encoding in Python (really check the documentation, nobody can remember all encoding names). Your error is not in Python code, but in not using the real encoding of the file.

Comment: @–Giacomo Catenazzi you right the Advanced_Meter.csv  has both show both integer and strings. like this 016,1,219,Alaska Power and Telephone Co,AK,Final,"5,380","2,259",.,.,"7,639",0,0,.,.,0,0,0,.,.,0,"5,380","2,259",.,.,"7,639",0,0,.,.,0
2016,1,221,"Alaska Village Elec Coop, Inc",AK,Final,"7,811","3,076",.,.,"10,887",.,.,.,.,0,.,.,.,.,0,"7,811","3,076",.,.,"10,887",.,.,.,.,

Comment: There is a 0xA5 in the file (see title of the question). That it is the problem. You should check which company. But reading your CSV, the file is not in Chinese, so no GBK codec. Try with `cp1252` or `ansi` (or `cp437` if it is an old DOS file).

Comment: @Giacomo Catenazzi yes the file is in Chinese when i open TN_trapdoor in notepad it is in chinese language 錃嗎傗?虢?〡

Comment: so i removed these chinses character from my file and now i run the code without removing chinens character i get another   File "E:/Searchable_Encryption-master/Searchable_Encryption-master/sse_search.py", line 28, in <module>
    keyword_trapdoor = open(keyword_trapdoor, encoding='Advanced_Meter_index.csv').read().strip()
LookupError: unknown encoding: Advanced_Meter_index.csv

Comment: for more information i show this line of error keyword_trapdoor = open(keyword_trapdoor, encoding='Advanced_Meter_index.csv').read().strip()

Comment: on `encoding=` you should use just the std strings; `utf-8`, `ansi`, `latin1`, `cp1252`, etc. It is the name of the encoding, not a file.

Comment: right Standard Encodings method http://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings i trying and i dont need to remove the chinese character

Comment: Advanced_Meter.csv is the document that contains statistical AMI data provided by EIA.

Comment: try many encoding get different error mostly common error FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Advanced_Meter_index.csv' but i have the same name file in same directory